# Find trigonometric values of every possible angle

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I have read this answer [[Is it possible to all find trigonometric values without calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727746/is-it-possible-to-all-find-trigonometric-values-without-calculator]) about how to calculate every angle without a calculator but I find it quite a bit confusing and I am wondering if there are any other methods to calculate by hand the trigonometric values of every angle.

Thanks.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer which angle has computable trigonometric functions.

Well we know about famous angles $0,30,45,60,90$ in degrees and their integer multiples.

Then using addition and subtraction of angles, we can calculate exact values of trigonometric functions of $15^\circ$ and $75^\circ$, as well as $22.5^\circ=45^\circ/2$.

We know exact value of trigonometric functions of angles $18, 36,54,72$ in degrees, using a pentagon, or other methods.
For insance
$$\sin(18^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}. $$
Then we can compute exact value of $\sin(3^\circ)=\sin(18^\circ-15^\circ)$.

But note that $3^\circ$ is the least integer angle (in degrees) which its trigonometric functions are expressed in terms of finite radicals. This shows that any angle of the form $(3k)^\circ$ is constructible using compass and straightedge.

Note that, $\sin(1^\circ)$ is computible using the identity
$$\sin(3^\circ)=3\sin(1^\circ)-4\sin^3(1^\circ) $$
but in this case, it is impossible to cancel the imaginary unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$ 
from inside of radicals.

About trigonometric functions of angles of the form $\frac{2\pi}{N}$, for $N=1,2,3,4,\ldots$.

Among these, for $N\leq20$, the angles
$$\frac{2\pi}{7},\frac{2\pi}{9},\frac{2\pi}{11},\frac{2\pi}{13},\frac{2\pi}{14},\frac{2\pi}{18},\frac{2\pi}{19},\frac{2\pi}{20} $$
have no exact value of trigonometric functions in real radicals but it is astounding that the angle $\frac{2\pi}{17}$ is computible. In fact Gause did it.
$$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{17})=-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}\sqrt{17}+\frac{1}{16}\sqrt{\alpha}+\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{17+3\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{\alpha}-2\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}}} $$
where
$$\alpha=34-2\sqrt{17}, $$
$$\bar{\alpha}=34+2\sqrt{17} $$

Answer (score 1):

There is not a general simple way for that.

What we can do by hand is to start from the well known cases for $\theta =0°,30°,45°,60°,90°$ and use [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) and algebraic or geometric tricks to derive the values for trigonometric functions for other angles.

See also this related example here [How to prove $\cos \frac{2\pi }{5}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7695/505767).

Answer (score 1):

For very small angles, the Taylor development can do. But it will take several multiplies.

For arbitrary angles, I guess that the CORDIC method can be the most efficient by hand, though it requires a precomputed table of numbers. But the computations are just additions/subtractions and divisions by $2$, and a final multiply. If I am right, the amount of work will grow quadratically with the number of significant digits desired.

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/examples/compute-sine-and-cosine-using-cordic-rotation-kernel.html